# 一つのコンポネントを複数使う場合、同じpropsが表示される。

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

nuxtを使いながら、一つのコンポネントを一つのテンプレートの中に複数挿入して使っています。

各々のコンポネントのボタンを押すとそのコンポネントだけ数字が変わることを期待していますが、実際にはすべてのコンポネントが同じ数字になってしまいます。

EX)
大人[-] 1 [+] 子供[-] 0 [+] 乳児[-] 0 [+]
大人の[+]を押すと
大人[-] 2 [+] 子供[-] 0 [+] 乳児[-] 0 [+]
人あってほしいですが、実際は
大人[-] 2 [+] 子供[-] 2 [+] 乳児[-] 2 [+]

vuexを使ってない場合は正常に動いてました。

index.vue(page)

```js
<template lang="pug">
  section.container
      div.number-selectors
        NumberSelector(id="" name="hotel" class="hotel" title="部屋" type="室" v-bind:min=1 v-bind:max=6)
        NumberSelector(id="" name="adult" class="adult" title="大人" type="人" v-bind:min=1 v-bind:max=8)
        NumberSelector(id="" name="child" class="child" title="子供" type="人" v-bind:min=0 v-bind:max=6)
        NumberSelector(id="" name="baby" class="baby" title="乳児" type="人" v-bind:min=0 v-bind:max=6)
</template>
```

NumberSelector.vue(component)

```js
<template lang="pug">
  div.number
    table
      tbody
        tr
          td.-title {{ title }}
          td.-minus
            button.operator(v-on:click.prevent="number_minus(result, name)") -
          td.-amount
            p {{ result }} {{ type }}
          td.-plus
            button.operator(v-on:click.prevent="number_plus(result, name)") +
    input(type="hidden" v-bind:name="name" v-bind:value="result")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    min: Number,
    max: Number,
    type: String,
    title: String,
    name: String,
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return this.$store.state.number_result ? this.$store.state.number_result : this.min
    }
  },
  methods: {
    number_minus: function(result, name) {
      if(this.result > (0 || this.min)){
        const number_data = {number_result: result, number_name: name}
        this.$store.commit('number_minus', number_data)
      }
    },
    number_plus: function(result, name) {
      if(this.result < this.max){
        const number_data = {number_result: result, number_name: name}
        this.$store.commit('number_plus', number_data)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

index.js(store)

```js
export const state = () => ({
  number_result: 0,
  number_name: '',
})

export const mutations = {
  number_minus(state, number_data) {
    state.number_name = number_data.number_name
    state.number_result = number_data.number_result - 1
  },
  number_plus(state, number_data) {
    state.number_name = number_data.number_name
    state.number_result = number_data.number_result + 1
  },
}
```

説明が足りずコードだけ長くなってしまいましたが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

vuexは複数のコンポーネント間で同じ値を共有したい時に使います。vuexはSingletonになります。同じコンポーネントでも異なる値をもたせたいなら、コンポーネント内の`data`に持たせるべきです。
なので、vuexを使わないほうが正しいです。

逆にどうしても使いたい場合は、以下のように各項目ごとの`state`を用意してあげる必要があります。

```
export const state = () => ({
  reservations: {
    hotel: 0,
    adult: 0,
    child: 0,
    baby: 0
  }
})

export const mutations = {
  number_minus(state, number_data) {
    state.reservations[number_data.number_name] = number_data.number_result - 1
  },
  number_plus(state, number_data) {
    state.reservations[number_data.number_name] = number_data.number_result + 1
  },
}
```

合わせて`computed`も直す必要があるでしょう。

```
  computed: {
    result() {
      return this.$store.state.reservations[this.name]
    }
  },
```